# Do start conditions in a lexer (i.e., scanner) increase the ability to recognize tokens? Or it is just a convenient thing to have?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

At some point flex added start conditions. I'm curious to know whether this feature extends flex's theoretical ability to match tokens or if it's just a pragmatic solution that tends to make the set of rules (patterns and actions) shorter and easier to read.

There's some ambiguity here because it seems to me that start conditions could be simulated at the **C** level by clever use of flag variables; if true, then flex without start conditions is equal in power to flex with start conditions. Let's pretend we cannot extend our scanner this way, and all the scanner can do is match tokens via the patterns and echo back the name of the tokens. In this case, can the flex scanner WITH start conditions tokenize more languages than the scanner WITHOUT start conditions? Or can I always write a set of rules without start conditions that do the same thing as set of rules with start conditions?

Difficult question to word clearly but I hope I made it precise and clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They effectively allow you to run multiple DFAs with the same code. Another way to look at it is that it adds context-sensitivity.

It's done in Cobol for example where the lexical rules for PICTURE strings are completely different from those of the rest of the language, so you have

```
PICTURE { BEGIN S_PICTURE; }
<S_PICTURE>blah { ... BEGIN INITIAL; }
```

Comment: The value of your answer wasn't obvious to me when I first read it but I've looked further into my question and I now believe you are correct. It adds context sensitivity one otherwise couldn't have (at least in a single flex source). I suppose context sensitivity could still be achieved by writing multiple scanners with the supporting C code to call them but it's clear to me that start conditions do in fact extend the power of flex itself.

Answer (score 2):

Start conditions in and of themselves don't increase the power of the scanner. It is still implemented as a simple state transition table, or more accurately as a vector of tables indexed by the start condition number. [Note 1]

However, `flex` does not include any logic to change start conditions. That's done with your actions, which are written in C, a Turing-complete programming language. You are under no obligations to limit the state machine which defines the sequence of start conditions to something which can be implemented with a finite state machine.

For example, it is well-known that parenthesized expressions cannot be recognized by a FSM, so they are not a regular language. But there is no problem getting flex to recognize them with the help of a little stored state; it doesn't even have to be a stack, since only a counter is necessary:

```
%x IN_PAREN
%%
                  int count = 0;

<INITIAL>[(]      BEGIN(IN_PAREN); count++; yymore();  // Note 2
<INITIAL>[)]      yyerror("Unbalanced parentheses");

<IN_PAREN>[(]     count++; yymore();
<IN_PAREN>[)]     if (--count) yymore(); else { BEGIN(INITIAL); return BLOCK; }
<IN_PAREN>[^()]+  yymore();
```

#### Notes

1. Even more accurately, `flex` uses *two* tables for each start condition. One table is used if the token scan is at the beginning of the file or follows a newline, and the other one is used in all other cases. This makes it easy for flex to implement the `^` zero-length assertion operator. If a start condition has no pattern using that operator, then the second table is never generated, but the vector of tables still has two slots for the start condition.
2. The use of `yymore()` is to keep accumulating the text between the outer parentheses so that when the closing parenthesis is encountered and `yylex` returns, `yytext` will be the entire parenthesized expression.

Answer (score 2):

In my opion, **start conditions are fantastic**! It's NOT just syntactic sugar.

It's like grouping instructions in functions.

**Note1**:  with 10 start conditions we may divide your problem in 10 smaller "private" flex problems.

Example: try to write a lexical analyzer for (simplified) XML without start-conditions -- it is not easy!
         Define start conditions (inside_CDATA, inside-begin-tag, ...) things are much easier.

**Note2**:  By default I like to see it as a "automata of flex processors"

This makes a huge difference, for many problems.

**Note3**:  Instead of using just `BEGIN state` , if you use `%option stack` `yy_push_state(new_state)` `yy_pop_state`. Flex+stacks  you can deal with context-free grammars.  (ok, ok, if things become to complex, use yacc)

It is easy to write a *grammar inspired start condition stack based flex*

**Note4**:  start conditions can also be changed outside flex. (ex. in yacc)

**Note5**:  Writing code is telling a story! Remember we have notation that can can 
simplify your code, and to clearly express your message. We can write things like:

```
<a>re       {...}     //normal 
<a,b,c,d>re {...}     //multi state instruction
<*>re       {...}     //  all-state instruction
<string>{
   re1    {...}
   re2    {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, you're asking if by having a stack increases the number of languages that can be recognized.

As far as I know, no - it's only to simplify many repetitive tasks (such as having nested comments, or replacing special characters in strings). You can still only recognize regular languages using only the built-in functionality of lex.

You could still emulate the stack yourself in C with some effort and added complexity in the specification :)

Comment: Hi, Joao. According to EJP's answer and my own further investigation, it seems like start conditions add context sensitivity to the tokenization process; so I now think your answer, which was helpful nonetheless, is probably best viewed as incorrect. Interestingly (because I never thought about it before) it seems as if the lexer's grammar can be context-sensitive while still yielding tokens that "build" a context-insensitive language.